# Determine if the sequence is increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to determine if the succession

$$a_n=\frac{4n-3}{n+4}$$

Increasing or decreasing

To do so, take

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{4(n+1)-3}{n+5} - \frac{4n-3}{n+4}=\frac{4n+1}{n+5}-\frac{4n-3}{n+4}$$

Then I simplified the expression a little more by adding the fractions, however I don't know how I can really conclude the monotonicity of the sequence, any help?

Comment: $\frac {4n-3}{n+4}= \frac {4n+16-19}{n+4}=4-\frac {19}{n+4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{19}{n^2+9n+20}>0,$$and therefore your sequence is increasing (in the strict sense).